# Should you use protobuf as the datatype you use for processing or only for transmission?

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, grpc

I have a matrix struct written in Go.  That matrix struct has a bunch of methods.  I want to be able to efficiently compute matrix operations but I also want to be able to send it over the wire in order to distribute the computation.

I currently have the matrix and its methods separate from the protobuf definition.  When I need to send it over the wire I have to create a new `pb.Matrix{}` from the existing `Matrix{}` struct and then make my grpc call.  That seems like a waste.  So, is it a waste?  And should I just be defining my matrix struct as a protobuf definition and then use embedding to define operations on it?  Or is it better to keep them separate from each other?

Comment: "Better" in what way? Code size? Complexity? Architecture?

Comment: @Ainar-G Add "data transmission size?" to that comment

Comment: From my perspective, I would keep them rather separately and use some kind of adapter to create the pb. The idea behind this is to separate the transport layer that, if needed, could be changed simpler than if you "mix" it together.  But this is only my suggestion and point of view.

Comment: @Ainar-G good question.  I meant in terms of architecture and any overhead involved in converting between the two.  Not worried about code size and I think data transmission size should be roughly the same, no?  A minor difference is not important to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of architecture, I'd keep them separate. That would agree with the Single Responsibility Principle. In one of my projects we use this form:

```
type Foo struct { ... }

func NewFooFromProto(f *myproto.Foo) *Foo { ... }

func (f *Foo) ToProto() *myproto.Foo { ... }
```